# Программа выдаёт ошибку при использовании отдельной функции для динамического выделения памяти для массива

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Я написал программу, которая выделяет память для массива в отдельной функции, а затем в функции main вручную вводятся значения массива, после чего выводятся.
Когда я ввожу первое значение, компилятор выдаёт ошибку сегментации.
Компилятор: clang 9.0.0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void memory(int *parray, int mem)
{
        parray = new int [mem];
}

int main()
{
        int mem;
        cout << "Введите количество элементов массива: ";
        cin >> mem;
        int *parray;
        memory(parray, mem);
        for(int i = 0; i < mem; i++)
                cin >> parray[i];
        for(int k = 0; k < mem; k++)
                cout << parray[k] << endl;
        delete [] parray;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Измените вашу функцию на: `void memory(int **parray, int mem){ *parray =  new int [mem]; }` и вызывайте так: `memory(&parray, mem);`

Answer (score 3):

у вас указатель в функцию передается по значению, т.е. память выделяется для локального указателя в этой функции и память навсегда утекает после выхода из функции, поэтому вам необходимо отправить указатель по ссылке

```
void memory(int *&parray, int mem)
{
    parray = new int [mem];
}

int main()
{
    int mem;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов массива: ";
    cin >> mem;
    int *parray;
    memory(parray, mem);
    for(int i = 0; i < mem; i++)
            cin >> parray[i];
    for(int k = 0; k < mem; k++)
            cout << parray[k] << endl;
    delete [] parray;
    return 0;
}
```